# How can I programmatically add xaml elements in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, c++-winrt

I have a C++/winrt project with a complex and dynamic xaml interface created in C++ code. Now I am moving to the latest VS 15.9.0 Preview 3, which has platform support for C++/Winrt and also allows use of the xaml designer in such a project. But I don't want to use the designer and have turned it off in Tools/Options/Xaml. The result is that none of my programmatic xaml elements appears. The project seems to expect me to enter these elements in a xaml code page, rather than using C++, e.g. Grid(), StackPanel(), view.RowDefinitions.Append(), view.SetRow() etc. The GeneratedFiles folder is now full of items that were not present in the previous project, yet can't be removed. Is it still possible to use the C++ interface for xaml, and what must be done to enable it if so? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ryan is correct: C++/winrt does support programmatic creation of xaml, and it works great. With the help of a couple of c++/winrt guys at MS I think I also know why my code was not doing anything. In the former version of my app I had declared MainPage as a C++ class, not a struct, and had assigned the starting Grid for the xaml by getting the current Window and setting currentWindow.Content(theGrid). But in the new template app MainPage is a struct, which might matter, and while setting window.Content that way no longer works, this does: this->Content(theGrid). Leaving aside some irrelevant issues about declarations in the BlankApp, this I think is the answer. Programmatic xaml works if you set that initial content as above.

Comment: There is no difference between using `class` and `struct`. They are the same thing in C++, with the exception of the default access specifiers. Whatever you did, replacing `class` with `struct` is probably not something that changed anything.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, this is not the intended way to use this UI system. XAML-based UI systems are descendants of WPF, which relies on the Model-View-ViewModel (MVVM) pattern.

This pattern intends three types of classes to make up your application: Views, which are primarily written in XAML, and only deal with displaying data they are given; ViewModels, which are the wrapper and translator to give the views data, and to give the models commands; and lastly, Models, which are your backend business-logic classes.

Your instinct to not trust the designer is reasonable - it generates messy and unidiomatic XAML code. But it is an excellent way to preview the way your XAML code looks.

To get back to your specific situation, there are real problems in the library's API that will be serious roadblocks to programmatically define a UI in C++. Instead, you will want to use XAML to declare the UI. Adding and removing grid column definitions is not something that is well-supported, but using `StackPanel`s and `DockPanel`s is the normal way to do this.

If you have more specific questions, feel free to open a new question here, but do bear in mind that you may want to search first under the tags [mvvm](/questions/tagged/mvvm) and [wpf](/questions/tagged/wpf) in addition to [xaml](/questions/tagged/xaml), [c++-winrt](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-winrt), and [winrt](/questions/tagged/winrt).

If you have more questions that are rather broad and may be too broad for the main site here, feel free to join [the WPF channel on chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18165/wpf), but bear in mind that most of us don't have experience in WinRT specifically.

Comment: Thanks, Zarenor. Yet, C++/winrt has complete support for programmatically building xaml, and it worked great until I created a new project with the current VS Preview. C++/Winrt is pretty new - can it be that all that xaml support in C++/Winrt is now gone?

Comment: No, it's simply that the design of the library is pretty contrary to what you're saying. I originally tried to instantiate UIs in WPF programmatically (in C#), and you run into roadblocks where the necessary members are `private`, or`protected`, or missing entirely. I'm not *very* familiar with the API exposed to C++/WinRT, so I wouldn't take my word as gospel, but I know that wasn't the design of the system. I very much doubt the API has changed significantly between recent versions.

Comment: Again, appreciate the response. The cppwinrt support for xaml is (was?) pretty robust - I had no trouble at all creating a complex animated UI that was easily integrated with the program. And those calls are still there. I just no longer can get them to produce xaml. Wish I had some way to contact Kenny Kerr.

Comment: The nature of the programmatic support in C++/WinRT has not changed one bit, and support for C++/WinRT interop with XAML markup has only improved. The APIs are called the same way under the hood. I suspect you're encountering some other bug in your code or a configuration in your project.

Comment: Thank you, Ryan! I had hoped it was a configuration issue. Apparently the BlankApp created by VS when beginning a new cppwinrt project is not configured to allow programmatic xaml creation. Is there a place I could look to find what is needed?

Comment: This doesn't make sense. The XAML parser instantiates runtime objects programmatically. If the XAML parser can do it, then so can you. There's also no relation between UWP XAML and WPF. They are different systems, that opted to use similar XML schemas to describe objects. And that's really all. Besides, I have been using C++/WinRT for years, starting long before XAML support was available, so instantiating the UI in code was the only option. I never experienced a *"serious roadblock"* of which you speak. What are you referring to here?